# Can anyone help me to completely remove the background noise while I am talking in a google meet meeting from ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, zoom-meeting

I was doing a meeting over google meet.But whenever I switch on my microphone, other side persons are listening a huge amount of noise with my voice. It is due to the internal microphone of Ubuntu.I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 recently. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: before installing 20.04, was it fine ? there might be multiple reasons, in some laptops there will be more than one internal microphones that might cause problem, when you tried with external microphone how is it behaving ?

Comment: In Sound Settings, try increasing the gain of your microphone somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an entry to /etc/pulse/default.pa to add echo canceling to your input selections.

As sudo, in any text editor open up /etc/pulse/default.pa (I am using vi).

`sudo vi /etc/pulse/default.pa`

At the end of the file (on its own line) add the line:

`load-module module-echo-cancel`

Save the file and exit.

In a terminal restart pulseaudio:

type `pulseaudio -k`

*If there is doubt it restarted, you can check the process ID to see if it changes after you kill it. I usually just `pkill pulseaudio` because I can never remember the command.... Or if there is doubt, you could restart your machine (overkill). But the pulseaudio -k command should kill the current pulseaudio process and restart pulseaudio... I only mention because I have wrestled with pulseaudio numerous times*

Go to **Settings** ---> **Sound** (the graphical menu)...OR "**Sound Settings**..." if you're using a desktop with a panel(the speaker icon)...

On your "Input" section, you should now have an additional microphone selection with echo cancelling in your dropdown. Select that one as your input.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a separate microphone, and mount it away from your computer 's fan noise.

Muffle sound-reflective surfaces in your environment. Hang a curtain, a drape, a towel. Look around 360°. Do you see flat surfaces? Walls, etc. They'll bounce the sound back with a tiny delay.

Treat this as an audio recording problem. Use your microphone to record yourself (outside Zoom), listen to the results, lather, rinse, repeat.