# Background Noise in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS during any meet call

Tags: zoom-meeting

When i am in any meeting from my ubuntu 20.04 then lot of noise going from my side to meet members i also tried the solution given here [Can anyone help me to completely remove the background noise while I am talking in a google meet meeting from ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263481/can-anyone-help-me-to-completely-remove-the-background-noise-while-i-am-talking/1263493#1263493?newreg=1117f4a3ebf948dda145a01fdfd1b2a4)
But that also works only for 2-5 minutes can anyone help me.

Comment: My laptop's microphone also catches a lot of non-existing background noise. While I don't know how to fix the background noise with software, an workaround is to **use an earphone**.

Comment: Try this: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/02/noisetorch-is-real-time-microphone.html

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution actually the link in the question itself works but only when you are connected with any external microphone
when i applied this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263481/can-anyone-help-me-to-completely-remove-the-background-noise-while-i-am-talking/1263493#1263493?newreg=1117f4a3ebf948dda145a01fdfd1b2a4) then i tried it with my external microphone connected and when i removed that mic it will again start causing same problem so if you want the solution you must need an external mic.
if any other solution is available do let me know please